# How to fix error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, listview, android-emulator, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to get all the .mp3 files from the emulator and displaying it in the listview and trying to play the media file by setting onitemclick in the listview .I am able to display all the songs from the device but when I click the list item it show an ERROR .I have gone through almost all the E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648) error question available but not able to understand where to do the change .here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private int no;
private static final String SD_PATH =new String("/mnt/shared/New_folder_(2)");
private List<String>songs=new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
private void playSong(String songPath) {
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePlaylist();
    ImageButton play=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.pause();
        }
    });
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            playSong(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
        }
    });

   TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(no));
}
class Mp3filter implements FilenameFilter{

@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {

    return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
}
}
public void updatePlaylist(){

 File home =new File(SD_PATH);
 if (home.listFiles(new Mp3filter()).length>0){
     for (File file:home.listFiles(new Mp3filter())){
         songs.add(file.getName());
        no++;
     }
     ArrayAdapter<String>songlist=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,songs);

     setListAdapter(songlist);

 }
}

}
```

this is the error i am getting

```
2406-2418/com.union.musiclist1 E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

I have tried to set the onlistItemclick also but it is not working

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    try{
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH +songs.get(position));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

any hint will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

add the setAudioStream in your code.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), songPath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

you can try this. [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Comment: I have done that in playsong method but it is still not playing song

Comment: give the context in datasource.

Comment: using the following link I am calling the song on another activity and playing the song